# Spring Authorities not available in <sec:authorize> after login

Tags: spring, spring-security, roles

I'm using spring security 4.0.2 and spring webflow 2.4.2
In a JSF page, and using using ROLE_ANONYMOUS, I don't have any problems.

```
    <sec:authorize  ifAnyGranted="ROLE_ANONYMOUS">
        ...
    </sec:authorize>
```

But, after logging in, this doesn't work

```
<sec:authorize access="hasRole('ACESSO-BO2')">
            ...
        </sec:authorize>
```

But this works:

```
<sec:authorize access="isAuthenticated()">
            ...
        </sec:authorize>
```

The view knows it's authenticated but it doesn't know the roles for this user.

In my controller, this is showing the correct authorities:

```
Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
List<GrantedAuthority> listaAuth = (List<GrantedAuthority>) auth.getAuthorities();
 while (i < listaAuth.size()){
                  System.out.println(i+":"+listaAuth.get(i).getAuthority());
                  i++;
              }
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: What is the exact name of the role `ROLE_ACESSO-BO2` or is it `ACESSO-BO2`?

Comment: Well, you just solved my 3 day problem with this question...

The role exact name was ACESSO-BO2 (it comes from the DB)
After changing it to ROLE_ACESSO-BO2 and changing the code accordingly, it just worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: Either change the role or use `hasPermission` instead of `hasRole`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Spring 4 the `hasRole` functionality checks if the incoming role is prefixed with the role prefix (default `ROLE_`) if not it adds it to the passed in role (See [SEC-2758](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SEC-2758)).

You are passing in `ACESSO-BO2`, Spring Security is now checking if the user has a permission for `ROLE_ACESSO-BO2`. The latter is probably not the case.

Either change your security and prefix all permissions with `ROLE_` or instead of `hasRole` use `hasPermission`, the latter doesn't do the prefixing.

Comment: Thank you. Prefixing the permissions with ROLE_ did the trick.